# Are functions not in the azure-iot-sdk-c reference also supported?

Tags: c, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I am considering a system consisting of a custom module using azure-iot-sdk-c, an edgeAgent module, and an edgeHub module.

I used the IoTHubModuleClient_CreateFromEnvironment function to take advantage of the edge module.
In order to use this function, it was necessary to turn on use_edge_modules in "azure-iot-sdk-c/CMakeLists.txt".
And it was able to communicate with Azure as expected.
The official sample code is as follows.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/main/iothub_client/samples/iothub_client_sample_module_method_invoke/iothub_client_sample_module_method_invoke.c

Here is the main issue.

I noticed that the IoTHubModuleClient_CreateFromEnvironment function was not written in Microsoft's reference below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-JP/azure/iot-hub/iot-c-sdk-ref/

And I want to know if this function isn't referenced because of an update omission or if it's not planned to be supported by an experimental function.
Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And I want to know if this function isn't referenced because of an update omission or if it's not planned to be supported by an experimental function. Does anyone know?

It is supported and `IoTHubModuleClient_CreateFromEnvironment` is part of the document.

[Microsoft Azure IoT Device SDK for C](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-JP/azure/iot-hub/iot-c-sdk-ref/) is just a **reference documentation** which redirects to/from the [Azure IoT C SDKs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c), so `IoTHubModuleClient_CreateFromEnvironment` **is also a part of** https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-JP/azure/iot-hub/iot-c-sdk-ref/